# Method being called inside a test method returning null reference

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I am calling a method to validate passwords in an apex controller which is working by returning either true, false, or null

```
@TestVisible static Boolean validatePassword(){

if (string.valueof(reqParams.get(PW_KEY)) != null){
  Matcher pm = Pattern.compile('(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!#$%-_=+<>])(?=\\S+$).{8,}').matcher( string.valueof(reqParams.get(PW_KEY)) );
  return pm.matches();   ///true or false
  }
return null;
}
```

I am calling this inside an if statement in another method like so

```
@TestVisible
private static Boolean validateParams(){

  if (validatePassword() == false){ 
    /// execute some code
 }
}
```

The functionality is working fine.  However, when I try to run the test method It keeps giving me an 'attempting to deference null object' error

```
    private static testmethod void validateParams_haveParams(){
    Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>{
        'fn' => 'Test',
        'ln' => 'LN',
        'pw_key' => 'Password'
    };
      Test.startTest();
        Boolean actual = CommunityUserWebService.validateParams(params);
    Test.stopTest();
```

My question is why can't the test method find the 'validatePassword()' method.
I've tried directly calling it from inside the Test.StartTest()/Test.endTest() block and that hasn't worked either

Comment: Note that `if(value == true)` can be replaced with, simply, `if(value)`. Similarly, `if(value == false)` can be replaced with `if(!value)`.

Comment: Also, this isn't an issue of the test not being able to see your method (you'd get a different error if that were the case), it's about you trying to do `null.someMethod()`. it would help if you provided more of your class. Your test class calls `vlaidateParams()` with one argument, but the method, in the class being tested, of that name that you've provided doesn't accept any arguments. You should investigate how your `reqParams` variable is set.

Comment: If you were able to solve your own problem, please turn it into an answer and explain the what, why, how, and why (_what_ was the issue? _why_ is it an issue? _how_ did you fix it? _why_ does your fix work?) so that other people with similar issues may benefit from reading this question.

Comment: Mike, please consider restoring your post.